# What format does C3/D3.js JSON data need to be in for bar charts?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, c3.js

Exploring and experimenting with C3/D3.

Goal: To have external data from .JSON file to render within the c3/d3js bar chart. How do I pull the x and y data and apply it to the axis?

Current: I currently have a string of JSON data simply like this a bunch of x and y values:
`[{

   "x: 1540983600, y:16, x: 1541070000 y:25, x: 1541329200 y:20, x: 1541415600 y:21, x: 1541588400 y:10, x: 1541934000 y:15, x: 1542020400 y:9, x: 1541156400 y:4, x: 1541242800 y:7, x: 1541502000 y:6, x: 1541761200 y:1, x: 1541674800 y:6, x: 1541847600 y:1"
}]`

Current fetching data like this:

`const Url='/linktoJSON/data.json';
    $.ajax({
        url: Url,
        type: "GET",
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result)
        },
        error:function (error) {
            console.log('Error ${error}')
        }
    });`

Graph render:

`var chart = c3.generate({
        bindto: '#chartBar',
        data: {
            url: Url,
            type: 'bar'
        },
        axis: {
            x: {
                type: 'category',
                         },
            y: {
                label: {
                    text: 'Count',
                    position: 'outer-middle'
                },
                max: 10,
                min: 0,
                padding: {
                    top: 10,
                    bottom: 0
                }
            }
        },`

Comment: if that is your real json data and you expect it to render something useful you have a big problem. Look at the examples for D3 and use the same data format. Rewrite your BackEnd JSON provider code.

Comment: Correct. This data is purely just test data that I've written. I've seen alot of JSON array formats used such as: 

`var jsonCircles = [
{
"x_axis": 30,
"y_axis": 30,
"radius": 20,
"color" : "green"
}, {
"x_axis": 70,
"y_axis": 70,
"radius": 20,
"color" : "purple"
}, {
"x_axis": 110,
"y_axis": 100,
"radius": 20,
"color" : "red"
}];`

Then pulling the data like this: jsonCircles[1].y_axis;